# How can i create activties when pressing on Recycleview Item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

im new to programming apps for android in android studio with kotlin.

im trying to make my own application and i made a concept of how it should work but i cant really help myself, and it is hard to google it because i dont know what to google for.

What i have done already is to implement recylceview and did a class for adapt items in recylceview, setup room database, and all of this works...

**But now i want to make that when user press on Item-Button in Recycleview it should open a new activity with a blank layout(where you can add items in recylceview again). But now when the user creates another item in home activity and presses the button it shouldnt open the activity of item number 1, it should open a new activity with new blank layout.**

This is my concept how it should work like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the second activity that you want to launch already created, you can do the following inside your recycler view items `onClick` method:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MySecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

You want to keep the second activity generic here. So let's say your recycler view displays a list of recipes, and when you click on a recipe, a detailed screen is shown with more info about that specific recipe. In your `MySecondActivity` activity, you would have text for example that gives the user more detail about the recipe they just clicked on. You would pass this text into the activity via the intent.

```
intent.putExtra("key", detailedText)
```

And in the second activity you would set the text views text to the passed in text from the intent.

```
val passedInInfo: Bundle = getIntent().getExtras()
val detailedText: String = passedInInfo.getString("key")
```

The second activity will also need to be added to your manifest file. Something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MySecondActivity"
          android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I'd recommend reading through this link!
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so i did what you said:  it seems to work but is this really the way to do that, also each item hasnt its own new activity, if i delete one item, the activity switches? I mean when i add 8 exercises(items) to my new activity i need 8 more new classes to  get what i want. I dont wnat to create 100 classes or something like that

Comment: So you can have your initial main activity that has the recycler view `HomeScreen` for example. Then on the second activity `DetailScreen` you need to make it generic, and update its fields based on what is passed in. You can pass data to the second activity via the intent. `intent.putExtra("key", value)`. I've also updated the answer with some more detail!

Comment: Oh, thats a good solution, never thought about it, thanks, im starting with it :)

Comment: Hey, its me again. I worked at my app last day, and it is working now, but i used one more time my room database and saved all items in second activity in it again. By passing data to second activity, i pass the item name so that i can use it and save the items in second activity with the name of the item from Homescreen in database. OnCreate method I made a Query where it shows all items the User pressed in Homescreen. But now i have another problem. If the user creates the same Item with the same name, the same items would show up in second activity. Maybe you have an idea how to fix that.

Comment: Hmm, don't fully understand your problem, but it may be worth looking into using a View Model to store your data.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: Thanks, sry for my bad explanation of my problem :), i will look at view models , but i solved my problem using intent.putextra and room database